# different ways to initialize numpy arrays. which is which?

Tags: python, numpy

Being new to numpy and python in general, I'm going through numpy array and trying to understand what really is an array hape.

I have been initializing my array as:

```
x12 = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])

    = array([[1, 2],
             [1, 2]])
```

Today I just came across the following notation `(())`, which happens to be initializing the same array:

```
x12 = np.array(([1,2],[1,2]))

    = array([[1, 2],
             [1, 2]])
```

What basically is the difference between the two? is there any catch in using one of the the other?

Comment: No difference. `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]` is a list of lists, `([1, 2], [1, 2])` is a tuple of lists. Both are initialized to the same 2D array.

Comment: Often in Python lists `[1,2]` and tuples `(1,2)` can be use interchangeably.  Such is the case here.  There is one `numpy` exception - if the `dtype` is compound, the data must be provided as a list of tuples - making a `structured array`.

Comment: There is one syntactic catch which surfaces when your sequence has only one element: `(x)` is not parsed into a tuple, so `array(([x1,x2]))` is not the same as `array([[x1,x2]])` (the parentheses are ignored) A one element tuple can be constructed by adding a trailing comma: `array(([x1,x2],))`

Answer (score 0):

The `numpy.array` constructor works on [array-like objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array).

```
x12 = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
```

Here the array-like is `[[1,2], [1,2]]` which is a list `[]` of lists `[]`

On the other hand:

```
x12 = np.array(([1,2],[1,2]))
```

Here the array-like is `([1,2],[1,2])` which is a tuple `()` of lists `[]`

There is not much difference between the two objects as far as numpy is concerned.

Edit: see the first comment below

Comment: iterable is borderline wrong here. iterables that are not sequences do not work, they create a 0D object array containing the untouched iterable as its single element. Also, strictly speaking `array` is not a constructor (the class name is `ndarray`), it is a factory function.